# How to access a different Hard Drive through Ubuntu Shell?

Tags: command-line, mount, hard-drive, login

After I did an update on Ubuntu, the OS bugged out and wouldn't open any programs. So I decided to restart the computer hoping to fix the problem. Upon restart I realized that Ubuntu was locked into a Login loop. I tried several fixes to this, none of which helped, so I decided to reinstall Ubuntu. The issue is that I need to back up all my files.

The last time I remember, Hard Drives were located in `/media` on Ubuntu; however whenever I go to that location in a shell, the directory is empty. I'm not sure if the location of the Hard drives has moved since then or if the Hard Drive isn't mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Mount Your HDD partitions

Let us assume that `sdb` is your external hard drive and `sdb1` is the partition, you want to copy your data to.

Run `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` to mount `sdb1` to `/mnt`. To copy anything to external HDD run `cp <required_file> /mnt/<some_folder>`

Comment: Whenever I attempt to use that command, I get a message that says `Wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock`. after running dmesg, it says `new mount options do not match superblock, they will be ignored.` Another thought came to me though. Is it possible to access these Hard Drives using USB Instance of Ubuntu. this may be easier then trying to figure out all these problems.

Comment: Did some testing. Turns out I can do this through a USB Live. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: It is a problem in your OS. Post a separate question with those details and do close this question by marking the answer as selected.